# HTML Select Dropdown - Click Submit and go to URL based on Value

Tags: php, html, select, drop-down-menu

What I want to do is have an HTML drop down for example:

```
<option value="">Select Tire Brand</option>
<option value="cooper">Cooper</option>
<option value="michelin">Michelin</option>
```

And when they click the Submit button, I want it to go to **http://www.domain.com/{selection}/**

so if they selected Cooper it would go to **http://www.domain.com/cooper/**.

I would use the GET method and have it go to the main URL which is brand_results.php?brand=cooper but then the URL wouldn't show up as the neat URL which I use htaccess for.

Is there a way to do what I am looking for?

Thank you!

Comment: the second part of the question is not clear.

Comment: I agree.  I assumed he meant "I'm posting my form and thought of redirecting using GET..." or something similar to that, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming the value of name for your `<select>` is `mySelect` below.

After submission:

```
<?php
    if(empty($_POST['mySelect'])) {
        // User did not select a brand
    }
    header('Location: http://www.domain.com/' . urlencode($_POST['mySelect']));
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: No worries, as long as we could help.

Answer (score 2):

In the file that receives the result:

```
header("Location: http://domain.com/".$_GET['brand']);
exit();
```